# Why does functions in F# implemented in such a way?

Tags: f#

F# function is very different from normal CLR method because of currying support. For example function

```
let inc a = a + 1
```

Will have type `Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc<int,int>`. It creates problems with C# interoperability. Functions must be designed specially to be easily called from C#.

What is the rationale behind this design? I believe that the reason is currying support. But currying can be implemented using closures. For example this code:

```
let add a b = a + b
let inc = add 1
```

can be easily transformed into this by the compiler:

```
let add a b = a + b
let inc = fun x -> add 1 + x
```

both add and inc in this case can be normal `System.Func` objects. I believe that there is some interesting reasons behind this design decision.

Comment: You will probably have better luck emailing Don Syme / someone else on the F# team.  Although I am reasonably sure the whole reason is for currying, which might not be so simple for a more complex case.

Comment: I believe Don Syme and other F# team members are also a SO users.

Comment: Don Syme isn't but Tomas Petricek is and Brian is also part of the F# team (I think).

Comment: @JohnPalmer I pretty sure Keith B. is also here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as I remember, the motivation for having a separate type for functions in F# was performance (in earlier versions `FSharpFunc<...>` was actually called `FastFunc<...>`). I'm not entirely sure about the recent developments (I'm sure the F# team did some tests to find out whether delegates would work in Visual Studio 2010), but here is how I understood the problem:

If you have a function `add : int -> int -> int` then the function could be represented as a delegate `Func<int, Func<int, int>>` (using the curried representation). The problem is that very often you will want to call it with both parameters like `add 1 2`.

Using the representation with nested `Func` types, this would compile to `add.Invoke(1).Invoke(2)`.

However, when compiling function like `add`, the F# compiler actually creates a new class, say, `AddClass` which *inherits* from `FSharpFunc<int, FSharpFunc<int, int>>` *and* adds an additional `Invoke` overload with two arguments. This means that, in most of the cases, `add 1 2` can be compiled to just a single call `add.Invoke(1, 2)`.

This design makes F# code faster. It complicates the interoperability slightly, but not too much. It is fairly easy to write an F# member or function that takes a delegate:

```
let foo (inc : Func<int, int>) = inc.Invoke(41)
```

(You just need to add type annotations and then call `f.Invoke` - but you can also use `f.Inokve` as a first-class value and pass it to other functions)

Comment: Also notable is that F# supports targeting .NET 2.0, but `System.Func<>` and `System.Action<>` were only introduced in .NET 3.5.

Comment: Wow, this is very interesting implementation detail. Thanks!

Comment: Here is one more reason why F# functions are faster: CLI actions/functions inherit from System.MulticastDelegate. They iterate an internal invocation list when they are called, F# functions do not.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the F# representation supports big step semantics whereas `System.Func` does not.

Comment: What is "big step semantics"? I guess this is some kind of function aggregation, when compiler can create large function from smaller ones. Is it right?

Comment: Yes. You don't want to create temporary closures each time you apply another curried argument so you spot when you can apply several curried arguments at once and skip the temporaries, make a "big step". OCaml popularised this whereas Standard ML tended to avoid currying.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to interop with C# is to wrap everything in class/members. C# never has to see the inner workings of the member.